# Is there a command to spawn blocks in the air with worldedit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-worldedit

I went to the End and it was empty. So I fell, switched to creative mode and flew to avoid dying.

I need to make a floating block to 1) build from and 2) give me a visual point of reference to search for the End island.

Is there a way to make a floating block using world edit, maybe by coordinates?

Comment: Command block item ID is 137. You can do something to the effect of //set 137. I dont know if set will specifically work in your case however,

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone
```

Answer (score 4):

Easily, using the region-select commands and then the region commands that set the area to a certain block. See [the full list of commands](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Reference).

For example: `//sel cuboid`, `//pos1`, move up one block, `//pos2`, `//set 1` to make the air in a one-block region stone.

However, I doubt you'll find the End island this way. If the End is empty and you're not standing on a slab of obsidian, you probably got there through commands instead of an End Portal. I believe that the End doesn't spawn anything until you go through an End Portal once. So do that.

Answer (score 3):

Just do `/up <how high you want it to be>`.

> This will move you up a certain number of blocks. You cannot pass through walls with this command and a glass block will be placed at your feet to support you. *([source](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Getting_around#Ascending_up_an_arbitrary_distance))*

Comment: ["This will move _you_ up ... and a glass block will be placed at your feet"](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Getting_around#Ascending_up_an_arbitrary_distance) - you should include that in your answer

Answer (score 1):

do

> /execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~1 ~2 ~1 ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 dirt

in a command block to make a platform underneath you

Comment: They specifically wanted to do this using WorldEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `/setblock ~ ~-1 ~ bedrock`. You don't need a command block for that, and you don't need world edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/fill [x1] [y1] [z1] [x2] [y2] [z2] [block]`
You can fill up to 32,000 blocks. However, it will only appear in a rectangular prism.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why the gent saying "/up" was downvoted. Perhaps because the full command would actually be `"/up 0" or "/up 1"` but .. that is generally the command that you use with world edit or as he said .. essentialls you can also setblock but i find /up 1 a lot quicker in general.

Comment: I think because that command (and the one you're giving) was already given in an older answer, and because that user doesn't expand on their answer at all. It's good to check the existing answers to see if you're actually adding information or just reiterating it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `/up` if you have Essentials.